# Josh Smith's Article about MVVM, WPF, C#: How to close a specific tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabs

I've been adapting Josh Smith's example about MVVM in C#/WPF in my own application up to now relatively successful for a C#-WPF-beginner. But now there is one more barrier upcoming:

If any content changes werde made by the user on a specific tab and the user clicks after that the tab-close-button, a messagebox should be shown and informs/ asks the user: "Changes to the tab-content "Example-Tab" were made, without saving them. Hint: If closing, any content changes will be lost! Do you really want to close this tab?" If he then clicks the OK-button of the messagebox, the tab should be disabled/ removed and no saving-commands or something like this should fire. If he alternatively clicks the CANCEL-button the messagebox should only be closed and the origin tab should be displayed.

1) The messagebox-interactionlogic is no sorcery.

2) But how can I realise to close a specific tab? Where are the appropriated View/ ViewModel registered or deposited when closing a tab? I have in all my different TabViewModels' a boolean static method IsContentOfTextboxesChanged, that returns 
true, if any content changes were made to one or more textboxes, or false, if no content changes were made to any textbox-contents.

I have unfortuantely no idea how to close a specific tab! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got the solution.

**Change:**

```
void OnWorkspacesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
        foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.NewItems)
        {
            if (tab.GetType() == typeof(Tab01ViewModel))
                workspace.RequestClose += this.OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab01;

            if (tab.GetType() == typeof(Tab02ViewModel))
                workspace.RequestClose += this.OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab02;

            if (tab.GetType() == typeof(Tab03ViewModel))
                workspace.RequestClose += this.OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab03;

            // and so on ...
        }


    if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
        foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.OldItems)
        {
            if (tab.GetType() == typeof(Tab01ViewModel))
                workspace.RequestClose -= this.OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab01;

            if (tab.GetType() == typeof(Tab02ViewModel))
                workspace.RequestClose -= this.OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab02;

            if (tab.GetType() == typeof(Tab03ViewModel))
                workspace.RequestClose -= this.OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab03;

            // and so on ...
        }
}



/// <summary>
/// Closes and removes a tab of type Tab01ViewModel
/// </summary>
void OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab01(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WorkspaceViewModel workspace = sender as WorkspaceViewModel;

     if(Tab01ViewModel.IsContentOfTextboxesChanged) 
    {
        var result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "Changes to the tab-content »" + Tab01ViewModel.TabTitle +
            "« were made, without setting them." + 
            "\n\nHint: If closing, any content changes will be lost!" + 
            "\n\nDo you really want to close this tab?",
            "MessageboxTitle", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workspace.Dispose();
            this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        workspace.Dispose();
        this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
    }
}



/// <summary>
/// Closes and removes a tab of type Tab02ViewModel
/// </summary>
void OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab02(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WorkspaceViewModel workspace = sender as WorkspaceViewModel;

     if(Tab02ViewModel.IsContentOfTextboxesChanged) 
    {
        var result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "Changes to the tab-content »" + Tab02ViewModel.TabTitle +
            "« were made, without setting them." + 
            "\n\nHint: If closing, any content changes will be lost!" + 
            "\n\nDo you really want to close this tab?",
            "MessageboxTitle", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Question);


        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workspace.Dispose();
            this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        workspace.Dispose();
        this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
    }
}



/// <summary>
/// Closes and removes a tab of type Tab03ViewModel
/// </summary>
void OnWorkspaceRequestCloseTab03(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WorkspaceViewModel workspace = sender as WorkspaceViewModel;

     if(Tab03ViewModel.IsContentOfTextboxesChanged) 
    {
        var result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "Changes to the tab-content »" + Tab03ViewModel.TabTitle +
            "« were made, without setting them." + 
            "\n\nHint: If closing, any content changes will be lost!" + 
            "\n\nDo you really want to close this tab?",
            "MessageboxTitle", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Question);


        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workspace.Dispose();
            this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        workspace.Dispose();
        this.Workspaces.Remove(workspace);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more code, what is tab?  how is it instantiated?